# if Number (KD) is 0 redirect back - laravel 5.2

Tags: php, api, laravel

I'm working on the Halo 5 API, and I'm having trouble because when I enter a gamer tag into my search box, it will display their users stats, including their KD (Kill/Death Ratio. BUT, if a user doesn't exists I get this error message:

> Division by zero

because of this line where I'm calculating a users KD:

```
    protected function getPlayerArray($playerStats) {

        $array = [];

        $array['TotalKills'] =  $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalKills;
        $array['TotalDeaths'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalDeaths;


        // RIGHT HERE
        $array['Kd'] = $array['TotalKills'] / $array['TotalDeaths'];

        // If no gamertag found it will divide 0 / 0 = 0, then it throws error message

        return $array;
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid this error by redirecting back if its zero or something?

*(I dont know how to check if a Gamer tag exists on Xbox Live, so I have to do it this way)*

Comment: I got it working by inserting the KD logic into other method, check above

Comment: It seems you posted some sort of subscription key here, you should remove it immediately if it's supposed to be private..

Comment: You should change this key as it was exposed publicly so using it isn't safe anymore. I might be too careful here but it's a security issue and you must always do whatever it takes to ensure security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume we can use `TotalDeaths` to check whether gamer tag exists or not. Use a simple if statement in this case.

```
if ($array['TotalDeaths'] === 0) {
    // Gamer tag doesn't exists
    return false; // method that calls this method should check for false and redirect
}

$array['Kd'] = $array['TotalKills'] / $array['TotalDeaths'];
```

Keep in mind that `===` will not match string `0` nor `0.0`. You can use `==` if you really want to be sure you match every possible zero value.

It is rather poor way to check if gamer tag exists though. I suggest you to check it before you even call this function. You should also consider gamer tags that exist but have `0` total deaths.

Answer (score 1):

What if a player actually has 0 deaths? I know its probably unlikely (well maybe not for new players?) but its technically possible and your code should be able to handle it.

If I were you I would do a sanity check on your data before you try and math:

```
if ($array['TotalDeaths'] == 0) {
    $array['Kd'] = 0; // Or something that represents "infinity" but that doesn't make sense in this context
} else {
    $array['Kd'] = $array['TotalKills'] / $array['TotalDeaths'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by separating KD logic into other method and then just checking if spartan rank is = to 0, if yes, redirect back

```
class ImageController extends Controller {


    public function generate(Request $request) {


        // Validate email and password.
        $this->validate($request, [
            'gamertag' => 'required|min:3',
        ]);

        $gamertag = Input::get('gamertag');


        // Get data from API
        $playerStats = $this->getPlayerStats($gamertag);
        $playerArray = $this->getPlayerArray($playerStats);            // This is the array to be used when creating the image.



        $spartanRank = json_decode($playerArray['SpartanRank'], true);

        if ($spartanRank === 0) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        $playerKillDeath = $this->playerKD($playerStats);

        $XP = json_decode($playerArray['Xp'], true);
        $TotalKills = json_decode($playerArray['TotalKills'], true);
        $TotalHeadshots = json_decode($playerArray['TotalHeadshots'], true);
        $TotalShotsFired = json_decode($playerArray['TotalShotsFired'], true);
        $TotalDeaths = json_decode($playerArray['TotalDeaths'], true);
        $Kd = json_decode($playerKillDeath['Kd'], true);
        $GamesWon = json_decode($playerArray['GamesWon'], true);

        return view('stats')
            ->with('gamertag', $gamertag)
            ->with('spartanRank', $spartanRank)
            ->with('XP', $XP)
            ->with('TotalKills', $TotalKills)
            ->with('TotalShotsFired', $TotalShotsFired)
            ->with('TotalHeadshots', $TotalHeadshots)
            ->with('TotalDeaths', $TotalDeaths)
            ->with('Kd', $Kd)
            ->with('GamesWon', $GamesWon)
            ->with('playerSpartanImage', $playerSpartanImage);

    }




    protected function getPlayerStats($gamertag) {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/servicerecords/arena?players=' . $gamertag;

        $res = $client->request('GET', $baseURL, [
            'headers' => [
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => ''
            ]
        ]);


        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
        } elseif ($res->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return $result = redirect()->route('/');
        }


    }



    protected function getPlayerArray($playerStats) {

        $array = [];
        $array['SpartanRank'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->SpartanRank;
        $array['Xp'] =          $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->Xp;
        $array['TotalKills'] =  $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalKills;
        $array['TotalHeadshots'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalHeadshots;
        $array['TotalShotsFired'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalShotsFired;
        $array['TotalDeaths'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalDeaths;
       // $array['Kd'] = $array['TotalKills'] / $array['TotalDeaths'];
        $array['GamesWon'] =    $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalGamesWon;

        return $array;
    }


    protected function playerKD($playerStats) {
        $arrayKD = [];

        $arrayKD['TotalKills'] =  $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalKills;
        $arrayKD['TotalDeaths'] = $playerStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->TotalDeaths;
        $arrayKD['Kd'] = $arrayKD['TotalKills'] / $arrayKD['TotalDeaths'];

        return $arrayKD;
    }


}
```